# Equation always returning 0.0

Tags: c#, math, double

I hope someone can help me with something that MUST be a typo problem?

I'm trying to perform this equation:

```
66 * (1 - Math.Exp((-1) / 42)) + 0.0 * (Math.Exp((-1) / 42))
```

This is normal human way of writing it:

```
66 * (1-e^(-1/42) + 0.0 * (e^(-1/42)
```

Am I doing something wrong since I always get 0.0 returned?

Comment: You are dividing two integers here: `(-1)/42`. The result of the division is also an integer, therefore the fractional part gets truncated and the result is 0. You can get around it by writing it as `-1.0/42.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell the compiler you want to use floating point numbers either by explicitly using a decimal place in the numbers:

```
66.0 * (1.0 - Math.Exp((-1.0) / 42.0)) + 0.0 * (Math.Exp((-1.0) / 42.0))
```

or by specifying the type:

```
66d * (1d - Math.Exp((-1d) / 42d)) + 0.0d * (Math.Exp((-1d) / 42d))
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling it was something like that... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your division used 2 integers. So, -1 / 42 = 0.xxx which is 0 because of the integers (-1 and 42). You should use `double` to get the correct answer.

Thus, this is working : `double result = 66.0 * (1 - Math.Exp((-1.0) / 42.0) + 0.0 * (Math.Exp((-1.0) / 42.0)));`

Answer (score 1):

You're using integers and getting 0 as a result of rounding. Use e.g.:

```
double r = 66 * (1 - Math.Exp((-1.0d) / 42.0d)) + 0*_whatever_;
```

The point is that `-1/42` rounds to 0 (integers), so your exp() ends up being 1.  However, `double d = -1.0d/42.0d` will get you what you expect.